# Measure of neatness of a file tree

Tags: entropy, graph-theory

I'm working on a way to calculate the "neatness" of any file system tree.

Features I'm considering include:

- depth of directory from root
- neatness of child directories
- number of files/child directories
- number of file types in a directory
- uniformity in file naming within a directory
- is a file a duplicate of a file found elsewhere
- uniformity in file naming

My question is: What topic/branch of statistics covers an analysis such as this? *

* "Directed Acyclic Graph complexity" seems to cover directory structure, but doesn't offer much in terms of scoring the node (directory) in terms of content.

EDIT: To clarify, I'm not looking for specific software suggestions that already implement something like this. I'm in interested in what branch of algorithms cover this sort of computation. I would then implement this myself and be able to plug in and refine the individual metrics.

Comment: I think you are looking for "Applied Graph Theory/Set Theory" stuff rather than "Statistics". When I did some courses on [data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure) designs the actual "Statistics content" was minimal. There is a field called "Analysis of Network Data" but that is mostly related to the analysis of the "leaves" of a tree/network and how the internal structure affect them rather than a holistic approach... (I won't even go to clique detection, reciprocity, homophily and similar network-related concepts...)

Answer (score 1):

There is no single branch of mathematics/statistics that is going to cover this particular problem.  It appears to be a custom problem with multiple elements that would be described by different areas of mathematics/statistics.  As you correctly point out, the directory/file structure can be represented as a [Directed Acyclic Graphs (DAG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph).  However, this structure will only capture the specification of files and directories as objects, and the directed relationships between them.  You will need to augment this with descriptors for the node types (directory folders and particular file types) and any other associated properties for particular nodes (e.g., file names).

Your problem involves quantification of a system of this kind based on a number of factors.  It is a complex problem that will require you to specify what you consider to be more or less "neat" about a file structure.  I strongly suggest you break it down into some simpler problems to first isolate how you want to measure "neatness" of particular things.  For example, start by ignoring file names and consider some simple directory structures with different file types.  Consider what constitutes "neatness" in these simple file structures, and what properties you want your neatness metric to obey (e.g., is it neater to keep files of the same type in the same directory and separate them from files of other types, or is it neater to have files of the same type spread across directories).

What you are describing sounds to me like a long and complicated project that will involve breaking things down into simpler questions first.  There are aspects of it that may be similar to measuring entropy, but the problem you are describing is much more complex than that.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm working on a way to calculate the "neatness" of any file system tree.

You'll need to add a few subroutines but you can use something like SequoiaView TreeMaps.

Some of the programs written after the SequoiaView paper are:

- [ADirStat, WinDirStat and KDirStat](https://windirstat.net/background.html), see Bernhard's comments about his programs at that link.

The [KDirStat](http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/) webpage says it's project is no longer supported and suggests use of [QDirStat](https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat/blob/master/README.md), KDirStat without any KDE. QDirStat has a number of new features compared to KDirStat.

Currently maintained by Stefan Hundhammer, the [QDirStat and K4DirStat](https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat/blob/master/README.md) programs are an 80% rewrite of the 2006 KDirStat code. See further information by Harry Mangalam at: "[Using kdirstat for clusters](http://moo.nac.uci.edu/~hjm/kdirstat/kdirstat-for-clusters.html)". Also see [Baobab and Duc](http://moo.nac.uci.edu/~hjm/kdirstat/kdirstat-for-clusters.html#_baobab).

All those programs came after the [SequoiaView](http://www.win.tue.nl/sequoiaview/) paper, which is based upon representation of TreeMaps in the least amount of screen space. TreeMaps were developed by developed by Shneiderman and Johnson in the late 1980's, a newer webpage (working) is "[Treemaps for space-constrained visualization of hierarchies](http://www.cs.umd.edu/hcil/treemap-history/)".

> My question is: What topic/branch of statistics covers an analysis such as this? "Directed Acyclic Graph complexity" seems to cover directory structure, but doesn't offer much in terms of scoring the node (directory) in terms of content.

For things such as: "neatness of child directories" or "uniformity in file naming" you'll need subroutines that define exactly what you mean and apply themselves to each directory. Uniformity *could* involve something as simple as string comparison, or more elaborate if you wish.

What's important is the research, development, and body of source code that has been refined over the years; available for Android, Linux, and Windows. On enormous and deep filesystems this software is quite fast and presents a visualization of your filesystem that, once you get your head around it, is very easy to understand.

Another bonus is that if you come up with a great idea you can choose to contribute it to the project if you wish - which provides the benefit of thousands more eyes working to improve your idea.